# Как добавить новый элемент в json_array в Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся со следующей задачей: у меня есть определенная модель Model, со свойством, которое меняется с течением времени (history). Эти изменения мне необходимо хранить в истории, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать для статистики. Для хранения всей истории в базе я решил, что будет разумно указать тип для свойства history - json_array. И хранить эту историю в одной ячейке в самой базе.

Соответственно, вопрос: 
Сейчас мне при каждом изменении свойства нужно создавать объект, получать текущее значение истории, т.е. получать актуальный массив, добавлять в него новое значение, сохранять массив. Это осуществляется следующим кодом:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Model')->find($id);
$history = $entity->getHistory();
$history[date('Y-m-d H:i:s')] = $currentValue;
$entity->setHistory();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Чувствую, что это извращение. Можно ли как-то проще решить такую задачу, используя Symfony и Doctrine?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это вы зря историю в массиве храните

Comment: @Etki честно сказать, в моем случае не придумал варианта лучше.

Comment: А как Вы бы посоветовали хранить историю? В отдельной таблице?

Comment: Да, так вы рискуете начать оперировать большими объемами данных (на каждый чих запись и чтение большого массива). Строго говоря, это не факт что и заметно будет, но как rule of thumb - всегда надо ограничивать объем данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так добавьте в самой моделе `AppBundle:Model` новый метод, вида:

```
public function saveValueIntoHistory($currentValue)
{
    $this->history[date('Y-m-d H:i:s')] = $currentValue;
}
```

А уже в самом экшене будет:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Model')->find($id);
$entity->saveValueIntoHistory(currentValue);
$em->flush();
```

Здесь сознательно пропущен вызов метода `persist`, т.к. получив сущность из БД она уже является отслеживаемой в Doctrine. Вызывать `persist` нужно только при желании создать новую сущность, которой ещё нет в БД. А если вы сначала получили её `find`-ом, то дополнительный `persist` лишь проверит наличие этого объекта в контейнере Doctrine.

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за комментарий про persist. Не знал о таком нюансе.